# Python не видит SSL сертификат на Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ssl

Стоит 16.04 Ubuntu, предустановленный python2.7, установленный через sudo apt install python3.5 и python3.11 установленный через исходный код. Python3.11 ставил так:

```
cd python-3.11.0
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make install
```

Ошибка возникает при попытке загрузить библиотеку через pip от python3.11 (потому что pip от python3.5 работает нормально).Ошибка такая:

> There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed

Кроме того возникает ошибка ssl сертификата при попытке создания нового проекта в PyCharm с использованием интерпретатора от Python3.11 (у интерпретатора Python3.5 ошибок нет в PyCharm).
Пробовал разные методы, в т.ч. скачивание и установку openssl-3.0.7, но не помогло.
Если я делаю поиск по имени "ssl", у меня выдает такой результат:

```
find / -name "ssl" > /home/alex/file.txt

/home/alex/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.3/ssl
/home/alex/Python-3.11.0/Tools/ssl
/snap/core18/2654/etc/ssl
/snap/core18/2654/usr/lib/ssl
/snap/core18/2667/etc/ssl
/snap/core18/2667/usr/lib/ssl
/snap/snapd/17883/var/lib/snapd/ssl
/snap/snapd/17950/var/lib/snapd/ssl
/var/lib/snapd/ssl
/etc/cups/ssl
/etc/ssl
/usr/local/openssl/ssl
/usr/share/doc/libssl-doc/demos/ssl
/usr/lib/ssl
```

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема на Python3.11 ? Есть ли смысл устанавливать, например, Python3.10 через sudo apt install, учитывая что мне нельзя допустить конфликта с версией python3.5 ?

Comment: `pip install пакет config --global http.sslVerify false` взято отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi

Comment: @Dmitry Kozlov , спасибо. Я продвинулся, но получил новую ошибку с setup файлом... "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1". Буду искать дальше.

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить. А чем обсусловлено старое окружение? Ну т.е. почему проблема пытается решиться в старом бубне?